# TextFields not Appeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I am a new iOS developer. I am animating the fields and I want to enter data into the fields. I am using the following code.

Text isn't appearing. It is going up. Please help me.

```
if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(theStatusBarOrientation)
    keyboardShiftAmount = keyboardFrame.size.width;
else 
    keyboardShiftAmount = keyboardFrame.size.height;

[UIView beginAnimations: @"ShiftUp" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: keyboardSlideDuration];
NSLog(@"%f",keyboardShiftAmount);
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,
                               self.view.center.y - keyboardShiftAmount);
[UIView commitAnimations];
viewShiftedForKeyboard = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [uitextfielddelegate](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/) to make animations